# Cant iterate 3 levels deep Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having some trouble iterating 3 to 4 levels deep. Here is my firebase code:

```
users
KEY1:
    foo:
        bar:
           KEY2.0:
               bat:
                   KEY3:
                       variable: "this value"
                   KEY3:
                       variable: "that value"
           KEY2.1:
               bat:
                   KEY3.0:
                       variable: "this value"
                   KEY3.1:
                       variable: "that value"
```

Here is my:

```
func get() {
    let Ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "users").child(AppState.sharedInstance.userUUID).child("foo").child("bar")
    Ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        var newResults: [Something] = []
        for Items in snapshot.children {
            let results = Something(snapshot: Items as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            self.id = results.key
            let Ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "users").child(AppState.sharedInstance.userUUID).child("foo").child("bar").child(self.id).child("bat")
            var newResults: [Other] = []
            Ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                for Items in snapshot.children {
                    let results = InstagramLikes(snapshot: Items as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                    newResults.append(results)
                }
                self.Results = newResults
                NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.sortTableData(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "reload"), object: nil)
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "reload"), object: nil)
                print("Data Streaming")

            })
        }
    })
}
```

and the "Other" model:

```
struct Other {

var key: String
var variable: String
let ref: FIRDatabaseReference?

init(variable: String, key: String = "") {
    self.key = key
    self.variable = variable
    self.ref = nil
}

init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
    key = snapshot.key
    variable = ""
    ref = snapshot.ref
    if key != "count" {
        let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
        variable = snapshotValue["variable"] as! String
    }

}

func toAnyObject() -> Any {
    print("return")
    return [
        "variable": variable,
    ]
}



}
```

The "Something" model:

```
struct Other {

var key: String
var variable: String
let ref: FIRDatabaseReference?

init(variable: String, key: String = "") {
    self.key = key
    self.variable = variable
    self.ref = nil
}

init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
    key = snapshot.key
    variable = ""
    ref = snapshot.ref
    if key != "count" {
        let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
        variable = snapshotValue["variable"] as! String
    }

}

func toAnyObject() -> Any {
    print("return")
    return [
        "variable": variable,
    ]
}



}
```

So what I'm trying to do is for each user/KEY1 I want to get the total variables from each KEY3 for each KEY2 and append them to a list. Currently with my code it gets the KEY3 values for each KEY2 item, however it appends and then seems to clear that value everytime. I hope its a simple fix. I've been at this all weekend.